# Changing the ALSA volume remotely

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi (called Igor) in my room that plays music, and occasionally speaks a warning message. If I want to change its volume, or mute it, I need to ssh into it from my laptop and start `alsamixer`. This is a bit of a hassle and I'd like to use some keyboard shortcuts, or an onscreen control, just for changing Igor's volume.

I suppose I could cobble up a small server on the RPi that listens for network messages and adjusts the volume accordingly. From my laptop I could set up keyboard shortcuts that do something like

```
echo "+10%" | nc igor $portnumber
```

for 10% louder, and `"-10%"` for softer. Create my own API, so to say. But isn't there already something out there that does that? Does ALSA have an API for network access? Or does PulseAudio?

Just to make it clear, I don't want to stream the music itself to the RPi. Igor has its own sources of music.

Comment: Run `amixer` through `ssh`.

Comment: @CL. That works! I will expand it to a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

@CL. gave me the idea of running a single command through `ssh`, triggered by a keyboard shortcut.

On the RPi, I have a script `softer.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Turn the volume down 10%
amixer -c0 set PCM -- $[$(amixer -c0 get PCM|grep -o [0-9]*%|sed 's/%//')-10]% > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This `get`s the current volume from amixer (which is a percentage), subtracts 10, sticks the "%" symbol to the end, and `set`s the volume to the result. Same for `louder.sh` which adds 10%.

On my laptop I set <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to execute:

```
ssh pi@igor softer.sh
```

and of course <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to

```
ssh pi@igor louder.sh
```

Comment: It works, but it's a bit laggy. Anyone has a faster solution?

Comment: I guess it's slow because it has to make a new ssh connection every time, did you ever find a faster solution?

Comment: No, and I haven't got around to writing a little `netcat`-based server that accepts commands over UDP, but one day, I will.

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot about this! In the end I wrote a nodejs http-server that runs the amixer commands. It seems to work pretty well, I can't perceive any lag. Happy to share if you're interested.

Comment: @user3432422 yes, please! If you need an email address, please find my website through my profile.

Comment: Will do, though might be a few days, bit busy this week!

Comment: Ah I did it already, here you go: https://github.com/ollyhayes/volume-server